# Cannot connect to mongodb on ec2 with pymongo, can connect with studio3T

Tags: python, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pymongo

I have deployed mongodb replica set on aws ec2 instances with one primary and two secondary replicas. I am able to connect to the database from another ec2 instance within the same vpc via pymongo, I am able to connect to mongodb from Studio3T from my local computer. The problem I have is I just cannot connect to it via pymongo on my local computer or I should say via the logs the connections is accepted and ended in 50ms for some reason.

- `EC2` running the mongodb is `AmazonLinux Version 2`
- my computer is: `macos 12.5.1 m1`
- `mongod version` is `db version v4.2.22`
- python version is: `3.8.10`
- The database is running, in active state, and it is running on port `27017`
- In the security groups I have added `0.0.0.0` to inbound rules with port `27017 TCP` protocol
- `net.bindIp` is set to `0.0.0.0` in `/etc/mongod.conf`
- I have tried `net.bindIpAll: true` did not change anything. (I have restarted mongod after changing these)
- I can `ssh` into the database from my local computer.
- I do not need to use a private key to connect. (I do not use private key files when connecting from Studio3T and ec2 instance in the same vpc.)
- ICMP protocol is open to all ports and ips in the security groups.

This is the logs I get in `/log/mongod.log` assume `1.2.3.4:12345` is my ip and port.

```
2023-04-19T10:40:24.448+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 1.2.3.4:12345 #140572 (47 connections now open)
2023-04-19T10:40:24.450+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn140572] received client metadata from 1.2.3.4:12345 conn140572: { driver: { name: "PyMongo", version: "4.3.3" }, os: { type: "Darwin", name: "Darwin", architecture: "arm64", version: "12.5.1" }, platform: "CPython 3.8.10.final.0" }
2023-04-19T10:40:24.497+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn140572] end connection 1.2.3.4:12345 (46 connections now open)
```

this is how I try to connect to the primary node:

```py
cli = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://username:password@ec2-1-1-1-1.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com')
```

also like this:(this is the connection string I get from Studio3T, Studio3T literally connects with this string)

```py
cli = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://username:password@ec2-1-1-1-1.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com/admin?authSource=admin')
```

I can connect from my own terminal using mongosh and using the same strings above.

I have also tried ssh tunneling from the ec2 instance in the same vpc, also from the instance running mongodb itself. Here is my also failed ssh tunneling attempt:

```py
server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('ec2-2-2-2-2.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com', 22), # ec2 instance that can connect with pymongo in the same vpc
    ssh_username='ubuntu',
    ssh_pkey='/path/to/key',   # I had to give the full path of the keyfile here
    remote_bind_address=('1.1.1.1', 27017), # public ip of ec2 running mongo
    local_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 27017) # trying to bind it to localhost 
    )
server.start() # server starts without error

# Connect to Database
client = pymongo.MongoClient(
    host='127.0.0.1',
    port=27017,
    username='username',
    password='password'
)
client.server_info()
```

Final note: I can connect to mongodb via Studio3T using ssh tunneling as well.

I believe I have scanned every stackoverflow post related to this but unfortunately still could not find a solution. Really open to any idea thanks.

The result of `netstat -an` in the ec2 instance running mongod:
[image: The result of netstat -an in the ec2 instance running mongod]